# Как с строки мне сделать json и работать с ним?

Tags: c#, json

Такая вот проблема: у меня есть строка полученная с сайта pastebin. Выглядит полученная строка вот так:

```
{
  "default": "https://www.google.ru",
  "custom": "https://ya.ru"
}


using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                if (Internet.OK())
                {
                    string readver = wc.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/15W32fsE3");
                    
                    MessageBox.Show(readver);

                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Нет доступа в сеть");

            }
```

Может кто подсказать как мне вставить данную строку в json и уже работать с ним?

Comment: `WebClient` устарел, используйте `HttpClient`.

Comment: @aepot окей, а как?

Comment: `private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` и потом в `async` методе `string text = await client.GetStringAsync(url);` хотя-бы так. Можно в try-catch обернуть, чтобы при ошибках не падало.

Comment: @aepot понял спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно использовать пакет Newtonsoft.Json.

Создайте модель

```
class ReadVerModel
{
    [JsonProperty("default")]
    public string SomeName1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("custom")]
    public string SomeName2 { get; set; }
}
```

Затем

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadVerModel>(readver);
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло.

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json` устарел, используйте `System.Text.Json`

Comment: @aepot а как тогда переделать "var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadVerModel>(readver);"?

Comment: @kanejons2 `using System.Text.Json`, `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ReadVerModel>(readver)`, а NuGet пакет Newtonsoft.Json можно удалить, он для устаревшего фреймворка 4.x только нужен.

Comment: @kanejons2 я вам больше скажу, можно сразу JSON получить из HttpClient `await client.GetFromJsonAsync<ReadVerModel>(url)`, да кстати, вместо `[JsonProperty(...)]` будет `JsonPropertyName`